# Execute a Grails script when a given dependency changes

Tags: grails

I would like to start a custom script when a given jar dependency is updated.

For example, say I have dependencies like this:

```
compile "com.foo:library:1.2-SNAPSHOT"
```

I would like to trigger a script whenever either of theese condition is met:

- com.foo.library is updated to version 1.2 (no snapshot) or more
- a new snapshot of library is released
- it is the first time I build the project and I have to download library for the first time

In other words, I would like to trigger it whenever library is downloaded, either from the network or from the cache.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will help you, however you can define a plugin dependency as `changing = true` or use `<version-number>-SNAPSHOT`

Assuming you're using the latest version of grails - The documentation can be found at [4.7.6 Snapshots and Other Changing Dependencies](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#changingDependencies)

You can also force the update interval.

Now.. as to whether there is an event fired when dependencies are resolved I don't know the answer. You might be able to hook into the build event.

Failing that you might need to delve deeper in Maven/Ivy documentation to force some kind of system level script to run and call some arbitrary grails script.

[Here is a blog post that talks about using the build event to take control of dependency resolution](http://viaboxxsystems.de/hacking-around-grails-broken-snapshot-dependency-mechanism)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is somewhat useful, but it's not what I asked; the documentation about events is so poor I wonder how they discovered the eventResolveDependenciesEnd...